# Implementing other listeners like "Aggregate Reports", "Summary Reports" and third party plugins in Jmeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I would like to implement the new listener in JMeter in which I need to extend Aggregate reports and summary reports listener which are available by default in JMeter. I need to get all data which will be available after the run. Can someone please explain me to how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Synthesis Report](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SynthesisReport/#Synthesis-Report) already? It is a mix of Aggregate Report and Summary Report and could be something you're looking for.

[image: Synthesis Report]

If it fits your needs you can install it via [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager).

If not and you need to add features - you can take a look into its [source code](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/tree/c449e936b27d91adf4acaf78590e7b9d8a6ad5df). Also check out [How to write a plugin for JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_tutorial.html) user manual chapter.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I would like to get all the data from the aggregate report and make it to json and at the same time, I want to get required parameters for creating graph too. For that, I need to implement third-party graph plugins.